# Can I use my computer's headphone output as an input on another device (android phone)?

Tags: audio, input, headphone-jack, audio-output, 3.5mm

So what I mean is this:
I put a 3.5mm male jackplug in the headphone output of my laptop, and then on the other end of the cord is another 3.5mm jackplug that I plug into my phone, so when I call someone (on my phone), any audio coming from my laptop is directed to my phone, and the person on the other end would hear it.

If the solution is as simple as I noted above, could anyone link me to such a plug? I don't know what criteria to use and wouldn't know if they would work. For example this one: http://www.scan.co.uk/products/3m-scan-audio-jack-cable-35mm-trs-jack-%28male%29-to-35mm-trs-jack-%28male%29-black

EDIT:
 Added an image for illustration
[image]

EDIT 2: 
For clarification: I'm trying to use an online soundboard with pieces of speech on my computer, and I'm trying to connect my pc output to my phone's input for the other person (the person I'm calling) to hear. I would still be able to hear the other person through my phone's speakers. Maybe there are other ways to achieve this I do not know of?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to connect the audio output of your laptop (which is stereo -L and R) to mic input of your phone - which is mono? More than that - the intention of an audio output is to drive a speaker which is unlike a mic. The input impedence of a speaker is very less which may not be true for mic... Think again

Comment: @Prasanna I have illustrated it for you:
http://i.imgur.com/Sxv8FCr.png

Comment: @Prasanna But yes I think that's what I mean. Is it not possible?

Comment: I would be surprised if it works without damaging the phone. Because the external mic sends signals in the band that would match with the phone mic input via the 3.5 mm jack. However, an external laptop sound output may not behave the same way... Do you see the point?  I would suggest that you use an old phone (that you may not be worried if it burns out) to test this - rather than testing it with the phone that you might be currently using

Comment: @Prasanna I do understand it if that's the case... I just did not know it worked that way. Could you suggest any other ways to achieve what I'm trying to achieve since both devices have access to a wi-fi connection and my phone is rooted?

Comment: What is that you want to do? Take and place calls from your laptop by connecting it to a phone - what is the background for this requirement - *update the question*

Comment: @Prasanna Thank you for your reply, I updated the OP.